I am having trouble using FreeRTOS-Kernel
I am trying to build Pico-RVD, but is requires FreeRTOS-Kernel. I have cloned it using:
git clone -b smp https://github.com/FreeRTOS/FreeRTOS-Kernel --recurse-submodules

I have also set up FREERSTOS_KERNEL_PATH. I am using cmake, mingw, and armcc, all of which are freshly updated. Here is the build process and error:
PS C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\Pico\pico-rvd\build> cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
Using PICO_SDK_PATH from environment ('C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\Pico\pico-sdk')
PICO_SDK_PATH is C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk
Target board (PICO_BOARD) is 'yd_rp2040'.
Using board configuration from C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-rvd/src/boards/yd_rp2040.h
Defaulting platform (PICO_PLATFORM) to 'rp2040' since not specified.
-- Defaulting build type to 'Release' since not specified.
Defaulting compiler (PICO_COMPILER) to 'pico_arm_cortex_m0plus_gcc' since not specified.
Configuring toolchain based on PICO_COMPILER 'pico_arm_cortex_m0plus_gcc'
Using FREERTOS_KERNEL_PATH from environment ('C:/Users/Matthew/FreeRTOS-Kernel')
Defaulting PICO_GCC_TRIPLE to 'arm-none-eabi'
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.3.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.3.1
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/VSARM/armcc/13.3 rel1/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/VSARM/armcc/13.3 rel1/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- The ASM compiler identification is GNU
-- Found assembler: C:/VSARM/armcc/13.3 rel1/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe
Build type is Release
CMake Warning at C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/tools/Findpicotool.cmake:28 (message):
  No installed picotool with version 2.0.0 found - building from source

  It is recommended to build and install picotool separately, or to set
  PICOTOOL_FETCH_FROM_GIT_PATH to a common directory for all your SDK
  projects
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/tools/CMakeLists.txt:138 (find_package)
  C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/cmake/on_device.cmake:33 (pico_init_picotool)
  C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/CMakeLists.txt:57 (pico_add_dis_output)
  C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/CMakeLists.txt:101 (pico_define_boot_stage2)


Downloading Picotool
CMake Warning (dev) at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.31/Modules/FetchContent.cmake:1953 (message):
  Calling FetchContent_Populate(picotool) is deprecated, call
  FetchContent_MakeAvailable(picotool) instead.  Policy CMP0169 can be set to
  OLD to allow FetchContent_Populate(picotool) to be called directly for now,
  but the ability to call it with declared details will be removed completely
  in a future version.
  C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/tools/Findpicotool.cmake:46 (FetchContent_Populate)
  C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/tools/CMakeLists.txt:138 (find_package)
  C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/cmake/on_device.cmake:33 (pico_init_picotool)
  C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/CMakeLists.txt:57 (pico_add_dis_output)
  C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/CMakeLists.txt:101 (pico_define_boot_stage2)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found Python3: C:/Program Files/Python311/python.exe (found version "3.11.2") found components: Interpreter
TinyUSB available at C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/portable/raspberrypi/rp2040; enabling build support for USB.
BTstack available at C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/lib/btstack
cyw43-driver available at C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/lib/cyw43-driver
lwIP available at C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/lib/lwip
mbedtls available at C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/lib/mbedtls
-- Configuring done (13.1s)
-- Generating done (1.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-rvd/build
PS C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\Pico\pico-rvd\build> make

C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\Pico\pico-rvd\build>mingw32-make
[  0%] Built target picotoolForceReconfigure
[  0%] Creating directories for 'picotoolBuild'
[  1%] No download step for 'picotoolBuild'
[  2%] No update step for 'picotoolBuild'
[  3%] No patch step for 'picotoolBuild'
[  4%] Performing configure step for 'picotoolBuild'
Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 14.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 14.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/VSARM/mingw/mingw64/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/VSARM/mingw/mingw64/bin/c++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
./C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-rvd/build/_deps/picotool/
-- Using the single-header code from C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-rvd/build/_deps/picotool-src/lib/nlohmann_json/single_include/
CMake Deprecation Warning at C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/lib/mbedtls/CMakeLists.txt:23 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.10 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- Found Python3: C:/Program Files/Python311/python.exe (found version "3.11.2") found components: Interpreter
-- Performing Test C_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_WFORMAT_SIGNEDNESS
-- Performing Test C_COMPILER_SUPPORTS_WFORMAT_SIGNEDNESS - Success
libUSB is not found - no USB support will be built
-- Configuring done (5.3s)
-- Generating done (0.4s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-rvd/build/_deps/picotool-build
[  4%] Performing build step for 'picotoolBuild'
[ 67%] Built target mbedcrypto
[ 69%] Built target errors
[ 70%] Built target elf
[ 78%] Built target mbedx509
[ 88%] Built target mbedtls
[ 91%] Built target bintool
[ 93%] Built target elf2uf2
[100%] Built target picotool
[  5%] Performing install step for 'picotoolBuild'
[ 67%] Built target mbedcrypto
[ 69%] Built target errors
[ 70%] Built target elf
[ 78%] Built target mbedx509
[ 88%] Built target mbedtls
[ 91%] Built target bintool
[ 93%] Built target elf2uf2
[100%] Built target picotool
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
[  6%] Performing test step for 'picotoolBuild'
picotool v2.0.0 (Windows, GNU-14.2.0, Release)
[  7%] Completed 'picotoolBuild'
[  7%] Built target picotoolBuild
[  8%] Creating directories for 'pioasmBuild'
[  9%] No download step for 'pioasmBuild'
[ 10%] No update step for 'pioasmBuild'
[ 11%] No patch step for 'pioasmBuild'
[ 12%] Performing configure step for 'pioasmBuild'
Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
loading initial cache file C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-rvd/build/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_cyw43_driver/pioasm/tmp/pioasmBuild-cache-Release.cmake
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 14.2.0
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/VSARM/mingw/mingw64/bin/c++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done (1.3s)
-- Generating done (0.1s)
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-rvd/build/pioasm
[ 13%] Performing build step for 'pioasmBuild'
[100%] Built target pioasm
[ 13%] Performing install step for 'pioasmBuild'
[100%] Built target pioasm
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: "Release"
[ 13%] Completed 'pioasmBuild'
[ 13%] Built target pioasmBuild
[ 14%] Generating singlewire.pio.h
[ 14%] Built target pico_rvd_singlewire_pio_h
[ 14%] Building ASM object pico-sdk/src/rp2040/boot_stage2/CMakeFiles/bs2_default.dir/compile_time_choice.S.obj
[ 15%] Linking ASM executable bs2_default.elf
[ 15%] Built target bs2_default
[ 16%] Generating bs2_default.bin
[ 16%] Generating bs2_default_padded_checksummed.S
[ 16%] Built target bs2_default_padded_checksummed_asm
[ 17%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/src/main.cpp.obj
[ 17%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/src/application/Application.cpp.obj
[ 18%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/src/usb/usb_descriptors.c.obj
[ 19%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/src/usb/usb_task.cpp.obj
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/src/utils/utils.cpp.obj
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/src/utils/Packet.cpp.obj
[ 21%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/src/console/console_task.cpp.obj
[ 22%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/src/console/Console.cpp.obj
[ 23%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/src/console/commands/debug_commands.cpp.obj
[ 23%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/src/console/commands/flash_commands.cpp.obj
[ 24%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/src/console/commands/pico_clocks.cpp.obj
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/src/gdb/gdb_task.cpp.obj
[ 26%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/src/chip_tools/PicoSWIO.cpp.obj
[ 26%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/src/chip_tools/RVDebug.cpp.obj
[ 27%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/src/chip_tools/SoftBreak.cpp.obj
[ 28%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/src/chip_tools/WCHFlash.cpp.obj
[ 29%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/src/chip_tools/GDBServer.cpp.obj
[ 29%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_stdlib/stdlib.c.obj
[ 30%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_gpio/gpio.c.obj
[ 31%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2040/pico_platform/platform.c.obj
[ 32%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_platform_panic/panic.c.obj
[ 32%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/common/hardware_claim/claim.c.obj
[ 33%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_sync/sync.c.obj
[ 34%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_sync_spin_lock/sync_spin_lock.c.obj
[ 35%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_irq/irq.c.obj
[ 35%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_irq/irq_handler_chain.S.obj
[ 36%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_sync/sem.c.obj
[ 37%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_sync/lock_core.c.obj
[ 38%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_sync/mutex.c.obj
[ 38%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_sync/critical_section.c.obj
[ 39%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_time/time.c.obj
[ 40%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_time/timeout_helper.c.obj
[ 41%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_timer/timer.c.obj
[ 41%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_util/datetime.c.obj
[ 42%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_util/pheap.c.obj
[ 43%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/common/pico_util/queue.c.obj
[ 44%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_uart/uart.c.obj
[ 44%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_clocks/clocks.c.obj
[ 45%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_pll/pll.c.obj
[ 46%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_vreg/vreg.c.obj
[ 47%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_watchdog/watchdog.c.obj
[ 47%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_ticks/ticks.c.obj
[ 48%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_xosc/xosc.c.obj
[ 50%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_divider/divider.S.obj
[ 51%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_runtime/runtime.c.obj
[ 51%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_runtime_init/runtime_init.c.obj
[ 52%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_runtime_init/runtime_init_clocks.c.obj
[ 53%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_runtime_init/runtime_init_stack_guard.c.obj
[ 54%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_bit_ops/bit_ops_aeabi.S.obj
[ 54%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_bootrom/bootrom.c.obj
[ 55%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_bootrom/bootrom_lock.c.obj
[ 56%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_boot_lock/boot_lock.c.obj
[ 57%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_divider/divider_hardware.S.obj
[ 57%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_double/double_aeabi_rp2040.S.obj
[ 58%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_double/double_init_rom_rp2040.c.obj
[ 59%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_double/double_math.c.obj
[ 60%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_double/double_v1_rom_shim_rp2040.S.obj
[ 60%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_int64_ops/pico_int64_ops_aeabi.S.obj
[ 61%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_float/float_aeabi_rp2040.S.obj
[ 62%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_float/float_init_rom_rp2040.c.obj
[ 63%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_float/float_math.c.obj
[ 63%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_float/float_v1_rom_shim_rp2040.S.obj
[ 64%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_malloc/malloc.c.obj
[ 65%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_mem_ops/mem_ops_aeabi.S.obj
[ 65%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_atomic/atomic.c.obj
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_cxx_options/new_delete.cpp.obj
[ 67%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_standard_binary_info/standard_binary_info.c.obj
[ 68%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_printf/printf.c.obj
[ 68%] Building ASM object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_crt0/crt0.S.obj
[ 69%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_clib_interface/newlib_interface.c.obj
[ 70%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_stdio/stdio.c.obj
[ 71%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_stdio_uart/stdio_uart.c.obj
[ 71%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_stdio_usb/reset_interface.c.obj
[ 72%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_stdio_usb/stdio_usb.c.obj
[ 73%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_stdio_usb/stdio_usb_descriptors.c.obj
[ 74%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_unique_id/unique_id.c.obj
[ 74%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_flash/flash.c.obj
[ 75%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/portable/raspberrypi/rp2040/dcd_rp2040.c.obj
[ 76%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/portable/raspberrypi/rp2040/rp2040_usb.c.obj
[ 77%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/device/usbd.c.obj
[ 77%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/device/usbd_control.c.obj
[ 78%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/audio/audio_device.c.obj
[ 79%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/cdc/cdc_device.c.obj
[ 80%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/dfu/dfu_device.c.obj
[ 80%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/dfu/dfu_rt_device.c.obj
[ 81%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/hid/hid_device.c.obj
[ 82%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/midi/midi_device.c.obj
[ 83%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/msc/msc_device.c.obj
[ 83%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/net/ecm_rndis_device.c.obj
[ 84%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/net/ncm_device.c.obj
[ 85%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/usbtmc/usbtmc_device.c.obj
[ 86%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/vendor/vendor_device.c.obj
[ 86%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/class/video/video_device.c.obj
[ 87%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/tusb.c.obj
[ 88%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/lib/tinyusb/src/common/tusb_fifo.c.obj
[ 89%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_fix/rp2040_usb_device_enumeration/rp2040_usb_device_enumeration.c.obj
[ 89%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/pico_bootsel_via_double_reset/pico_bootsel_via_double_reset.c.obj
[ 90%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/Desktop/Pico/pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/hardware_pio/pio.c.obj
[ 91%] Building C object CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/FreeRTOS-Kernel/portable/ThirdParty/GCC/RP2040/port.c.obj
C:\Users\Matthew\FreeRTOS-Kernel\portable\ThirdParty\GCC\RP2040\port.c: In function 'xPortStartScheduler':
C:\Users\Matthew\FreeRTOS-Kernel\portable\ThirdParty\GCC\RP2040\port.c:338:28: error: 'configTICK_CORE' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'configNUM_CORES'?
  338 |         ucPrimaryCoreNum = configTICK_CORE;
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                            configNUM_CORES
C:\Users\Matthew\FreeRTOS-Kernel\portable\ThirdParty\GCC\RP2040\port.c:338:28: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\pico_rvd.dir\build.make:1439: CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/C_/Users/Matthew/FreeRTOS-Kernel/portable/ThirdParty/GCC/RP2040/port.c.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:2261: CMakeFiles/pico_rvd.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:90: all] Error 2

I am not exactly certain what is causing the problem, but it appears that FreeRTOS-Kernel is being built in the wrong order because configTICK_CORE is declared in rp2040_config.h:70:        #define configTICK_CORE 0. The problem is that rp2040-config.h has not been built because the file that is causing the error is the first FreeRTOS-Kernel file that tries to be built. I think this might be the source of the problem but am not quite sure exactly what could be causing it. This is my first time using FreeRTOS-Kernel and I would appreitate any advice on this matter.
